# What are the prerequisites to understand how FPGA Zboard works?

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, kits

I have a computer science background. For my intern purpose I need to work with FPGA Zboard. I don't have any idea how it works. I have some knowledge on logic gates, not more than that.

It will be helpful if anyone let me know what prerequisites I need to cover, what fundamentals I should have knowledge on?

I was planning to buy some kits like:
[kit1](https://www.amazon.es/Conjunto-Completo-Iniciaci%C3%B3n-Controladora-Servomotor/dp/B01MQPT9OD), [kit2](https://www.amazon.es/ELEGOO-Iniciaci%C3%B3n-Alimentaci%C3%B3n-Servomotor-Desarrollo/dp/B01MXGST4I/) to get use to with this field. Will it be worth it for me as a starter or there are more better kits to get started with electronics world?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Bearing in mind your computer science background, please immediately understand that an FPGA uses a Hardware Descriptor Language to implement a logic circuit. It is not a CPU so it dos not run or execute HDL and that HDL is not a program. Important to grasp that from the off otherwise you can go up all sorts of wrong alleys. That aside, what have you found out yourself from your lengthy research on the internet, where that's untold mountains of existing written information on all this?

Comment: What's an FPGA Zboard?

Comment: Those Arduino kits are good for learning electronics. However, they don't have FPGAs. You should get one anyway, so you can learn electronics.